# fallback function how to call other function in contract?

Tags: solidity

When I send to contract address some coins, I want to call other function in fallback function, but I have encountered the followed error.

[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Solitaire {
    uint randomNonce = 0;
    uint[] randomNumArray;

    event Deposit(address user, uint256 amout);

    constructor() public payable{
    }

    function GetNonce() public returns (uint) {
        return randomNonce ++;
    }

    function () public payable{
        uint value = GetNonce() + 20;
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, value);

    }
}

contract CallTest {
    event logSendEvent(address to, uint256 value);
    event depositvalue(address sender, uint256 value);



    function transferEther(address towho) public payable {
        require(address(this).balance > 100000000000000000, "Contract address does not exist enough money.");
        towho.transfer(100000000000000000);
        emit logSendEvent(towho, 100000000000000000);
    }

    function deposit() public payable {
        emit depositvalue(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function GetBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    constructor() public payable{
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the fallback function of `Solitaire` directly? Or are you trying to invoke it via `CallTest`'s `transferEther` function? If the latter, the issue is that `<address>.transfer(...)` doesn't forward enough gas to make another function call.

Comment: yes， invoke it via  CallTest's transferEther function.       I have tested in remix , first I my account has enough coin and provide enough gas , the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Per comments above, the issue is that [`<address>.transfer()` only forwards 2300 gas](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related), which is not enough to make a function call.

You could use `towho.call.value(100000000000000000)()` instead if you want to forward more gas.

Comment: redix give me a worning: **security/no-call-value: Consider using 'transfer' in place of 'call.value()'.**

Comment: redix is wrong, please file a bug

Comment: This answer is right, but for the wrong reason. 2300 /is/ enough to make a function call, but it is not enough to make /that/ function call. Because `GetNonce` is modifying state (which costs 20000g gas).